# Model specification for firm relocation

Tags: econometrics, poisson-regression

I am writing a dissertation on the factors behind firm relocation. I have a dataset of firms’ origins, destinations, and the year of their relocation. I also have data on some characteristics of the origin and destinations (e.g. union density, % of college graduates, distance between the two locations).

I first intend to estimate a gravity model with count-data, using Poisson regression. The dependent variable is the number of firms that relocated from one location to another in a given year, e.g. 12 firms moved from New Jersey to New York in 1994.

**Which would make more sense - 1) using origin and destination characteristics as regressors or 2) using ratios of origin and destination characteristics as regressors?**

I found a paper that does the former: https://www.redalyc.org/pdf/289/28943151005.pdf (Table 6). However, my understanding is that the **origin coefficients capture the firm’s decision to set up there initially, as well as its decision to leave**. For instance, if firms set up at the origin destination because education levels were high, the coefficient on % of college graduates would be positive - but this is what firms liked about the destination in the first place, not why they wanted to leave!

I only care about the relocation decision, not the initial location decision. Hence, I feel like using ratios of origin and destination characteristics might make more sense. If there is a positive coefficient on the ratio of % college grads in destination to origin, that tells me that firms prefer to relocate somewhere with relatively higher education levels.

Is my interpretation correct? Would this be a better way to specify the model?

**When should I add time and state fixed effects in the Poisson regression above, and when shouldn’t I?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts as I am acquainted with a company that relocated from New York City to Raleigh, North Carolina.

Ostensible reasons include lower costs for rent, cheaper labor, available educated labor, escaping NY state regulatory climate and a means to trim the labor force since many employees were either unwilling or unable to relocate.

They were able to rent their currently owned building and then more favorably, from the vantage of taxes, lease a new building in NC and take advantage of the NC state tax incentives for relocating.

As such, a physical phenomenon that comes to mind relates to electrostatic forces. In particular, when a local electric charge buildup occurs, at a crucial threshold, there is a jumping to a low charge zone. This is also related to a state change or classification modeling approach.

As such, I would construct a positive and negative force index that is significant as a predictor variable in a classification model (move or don't move), which could also serve as a propensity variable for a Poisson parameter.

On the positive index, the reduced cost of doing business in the new location due to lower wages or offered financial tax incentives. Also, an expected reduction in labor force associated with relocating would be beneficial.

The negative index in a classification model could relate to particular business depending on a few high revenue performers or technical talent, that may not wish to relocate. Also, even the loss of low level employees who fill efficiently critical tasks may cause large losses. The loss of loyal employees may cause an increase in errors and other associated turnover costs.

I believe for credibility purposes, at least, some industry differentiation is likely needed.

Once select industries decide to relocate, we could have a [Poisson Point Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) or in a geographic sense, a spatial Poisson process.